# yslow simply says 28 component not added on CDN how can i get the complete component details

Tags: performance, testing, yslow

using Yslow tested my site performance, CDN column shows simply 28 component not on CDN. How can i get the component details which is not included on CDN?

any Ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After running the YSlow test and you're on the results page (showing the letter grade, etc.), click on the "Use a Content Delivery Network (CDN)" item on the left. The right side will show all the domains that YSlow considers to not be CDN, and the number of components loaded from each. You can then click on the Components link at the top of the YSlow results to see the details file list.

Screenshot example:
http://screencast.com/t/Kw955kpK

You can also get a good detailed view by selecting Tools | Printable View.